# Odd Keyframe bug in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, webkit, css-animations

I hope your friday evening is going great so far!

I've ran into a really really weird bug in Safari, I'll tell you the story about it here:

A few months back, I got an assigment from my web developer teacher to make a site with modern and advanced web technologies, and I deicided to make a re-designed landing page for the code editor 'Coda'. It's been going great so far, but a few days ago I implented a @Keyframe animation for an SVG file. It works great in Coda on my Mac, but not in Safari? I first thought that I made a mistake somewhere, but I've added both @Keyframes with and without the -webkit- prefix, and then I saw that it didn't work on my mobile devices either.. I'll show my code here:

```
@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
0% { fill: #41B9D1; }
20% { fill: #9BFF1B; }
40% { fill: #F27E18; }
60% { fill: #FFD700; }
80% { fill: #FF0066; }
100% { fill: #41B9D1; }
}

@keyframes color_change {
0% { fill: #41B9D1; }
20% { fill: #9BFF1B; }
40% { fill: #F27E18; }
60% { fill: #FFD700; }
80% { fill: #FF0066; }
100% { fill: #41B9D1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change_2 {
0% { fill: #127093; }
20% { fill: #FF0066; }
40% { fill: #FFD700; }
60% { fill: #F27E18; }
80% { fill: #9BFF1B; }
100% { fill: #127093; }
}

@keyframes color_change_2 {
0% { fill: #127093; }
20% { fill: #FF0066; }
40% { fill: #FFD700; }
60% { fill: #F27E18; }
80% { fill: #9BFF1B; }
100% { fill: #127093; }
}

#Shape2 { /* SVG path I'm changing the fill on */
-webkit-animation: color_change 10s infinite alternate;
animation: color_change 10s infinite alternate;
}

#Shape3 { /* the other SVG path I'm changing the fill on */
-webkit-animation: color_change_2 10s infinite alternate;
animation: color_change_2 10s infinite alternate;
}
```

And now to the weird part, the animation works fine on ANY other devices except for MY ones.. And that includes an iPhone 6 and a brand new iPad Pro 9.7" running iOS 9.3.1 aswell as a rMBP running OS X 10.11.4 with Safari 9.1. I've tested the site on 4 other iPhones(4S, 5C, 6S) and all of them work fine.. Although, the 5C ran the animation the first time and now refuses to play it at just like mine(although mine never displayed it at all).

I've ensured that the animation works separately and @Keyframes works fine on all devices, and yet only MY personal ones has this problem on THIS site... I've tested with and without private mode enabled. It's also worth to mention that it works fine in 3rd party browsers such as Puffin and iCab, and also when I open it with the Safari View Controller in different apps...

Does anyone have a clue on what's going on?
I can PM the URL to the site if needed as I wouldn't like to post it here publicly.

Thanks!

Comment: Very hard to answer without seeing the code. My first attempt is a bit of a long shot, but try adding a starting fill state in your SVG `<path>`, like `<path style="fill: #127093;" … >`. The `fill` value should match the first keyframe's fill value in your `CSS`. Sometimes this can make a difference.

Comment: Hello Andy, thanks for the answer!
That's where the fill is... I can make a fiddle of the whole animation.
Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/hrygw4vn/

Comment: (I seem to have taken too long to edit the comment)
It still refuses to work on ANY of my devices, I've also tried running it locally, aswell as using anothother Mac now... There's definitely something going on at document as I see the marker the developer tools use is constantly flickering, although why it only occurs on my devices, I still don't know.. But atleast it works in Chrome.

Comment: I will take another look later this evening.

Comment: Let's try a different approach. Instead of animating on `fill` color, let's animate on the parent's `color` property. We'll add `color: currentColor;` to the `SVG`, so it will dynamically assume whatever the parent's color is. I'm hoping this will work better because `color` is a more commonly used/animated property than `fill`. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/grjjad?editors=1100)

Comment: Alright, I'll talk to my co dev about it! I also tried clearing cache aswell as restarting Safari multiple times.. Just whatever I do it doesn't work on my devices only in plain Safari.. I'll try switching host but I doubt it'll work.

Comment: When you test my demo on your machine, on Safari, how does it look?

Comment: It works perfectly fine

Comment: Hi again @andy, I've uploaded [the site to another host now](http://port-80-m13c3k7f3j.treehouse-app.com). I've actually noticed it doesn't work there either... Any clue?

Comment: That link you just added to the new host says "workspace unavailable"

Comment: I see... Sorry I don't have any other server. Do you have any suggestion for a site I can upload it on? If not, I can upload it through GitHub Pages. It's a shame you can't send messages on this site.. My co-dev doesn't want the server IP to be public. Meanwhile I can leave the snapshot for the workspace so you can atleast have a look on the code. Excuse me for the loads of unused CSS selectors in the main.css file, they'll be cleaned up once the site is done: https://w.trhou.se/lrg0dsoxm0

Comment: There actually is a chat program here, but it doesn't becomes available at my rank until a certain number of comments accrue. Should be soon.

Comment: For now, feel free to reach me via gchat (antibland@gmail.com).

Comment: Ah I see, I was wondering why it didn't pop up.. I'll upload the whole thing on GitHub later on today, if that somehow fails I'll contact you through Hangouts! We did some testing yesterday and applying the animation on another SVG element worked fine..

Comment: Hi again @andy, the GitHub version'll be uploaded on Wednesday instead. If it's crucial to view the code fast, then I'll see if I can try getting a server set up!

Comment: Hello again @andy! I'm so so sorry it took such a long time to get it up at GitHub, but finally it is! https://github.com/TheCodingGuy/coda-landingpage Weird thing is that the animation worked for a short time, but once again it refuses to work on my devices only...

Comment: Similar to my demo, I would adjust your animation so it modifies `color` instead of `fill` and operates on the parent, and not the `SVG` itself. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I haven't tried that quite yet. Will it work since the SVG is divided into 2 parts with different keyframe animations?